# Filtering Records from List or Array

Tags: c#, lambda, hashset

I am trying to filter records in C# list or array based on following conditions -
We have unique sender and multiple Receivers.
Considering Sender value as 1,

1. If Sender is 1 and Receiver is 2 as well as Sender is 2 and Receiver is 1 then it should filter out those records
2. It should take highest time from above filtered result and return only one record (Sender, Receiver, Time and Val) for each Receiver.
   My First preference is filtering using lambda expression and putting in HashSet to return top time value.
   For Example, Input :

```
"secrets": [
    {
      "sender": 1,
      "receiver": 2,
      "time": 2000,
      "val": "This is Val1"
    },
    {
      "sender": 2,
      "receiver": 1,
      "time": 2100,
      "val": "This is Val2"
    },
    {
      "sender": 1,
      "receiver": 2,
      "time": 1500,
      "val": "This is Val3"
    },
    {
      "sender": 1,
      "receiver": 3,
      "time": 2500,
      "val": "This is Val4"
    }
    ]
```

Output:

```
"outcome": [
    {
      "sender": 2,
      "receiver": 1,
      "time": 2100,
      "val": "This is Val2"
    },
    {
      "sender": 1,
      "receiver": 3,
      "time": 2500,
      "val": "This is Val4"
    }
]
```

I have tried below but it is not working as expected:

```
int senderId = 1;
for(int i=0; i<receivers; i++)
{
var senderSecrets = secrets.Where(x => (x.sender == senderId) && (x.receiver == receivers[i])).ToArray();
var receiverSecrets = secrets.Where(x => (x.sender == receivers[i]) && (x.receiver == senderId)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Please add full [mre] including used custom types.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't seem to match your code at all. Please expand on your explanation or use pseudocode to describe the actual conditions for filtering and the results. Where did `receivers` come from in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If Sender is 1 and Receiver is 2 as well as Sender is 2 and Receiver is 1 then it should filter out those records.

```
Secrets.Where(x => (x.sender == 1 && x.receiver = 2) || (x.sender == 2 && x.receiver == 1));
```

> It should take highest time from above filtered result and return only
> one record (Sender, Receiver, Time and Val) for each Receiver. My
> First preference is filtering using lambda expression and putting in
> HashSet to return top time value.

```
secrets.OrderBy(y => y.time).FirstOrDefault(x => (x.sender == 1 && x.receiver = 2) || (x.sender == 2 && x.receiver == 1));
```